# Unable to use "scheme" attribute when plot GeoDataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, kaggle, geopandas, graph-visualization

I am rerunning the code in https://www.kaggle.com/skalskip/using-regression-to-predicting-earnings-in-france under Python 3.6, and in the plotting stage I ran the following code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(15,14))
ax.set_title('Salary by Departments', size=32, x = 0.25, y=0.90)
fig.patch.set_facecolor((202/255, 204/255, 206/255))
departments_map.plot(ax=ax, column="SNHM14", cmap=plt.cm.plasma, k=10, legend=True)
leg = ax.get_legend()
ax.set_axis_off()
leg.set_bbox_to_anchor((0., 0., 0.2, 0.45))
leg.set_title("Mean net salary")
```

I received:

```
ImportError: PySAL is required to use the 'scheme' keyword
```

The type of the dataframe departments_map is **geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame**.

I did `pip install pysal` and it showed that `Successfully installed pysal-2.0.0.`  But I rerun again the problem is the same. I referred to the source code of [/geopandas/plotting.py](https://coveralls.io/builds/7340305/source?filename=geopandas%2Fplotting.py#L291) and found the souce may be:

```
...
...
...
    try:
        from pysal.esda.mapclassify import Quantiles, Equal_Interval, Fisher_Jenks
        schemes = {}
        schemes['equal_interval'] = Equal_Interval  
        schemes['quantiles'] = Quantiles    
        schemes['fisher_jenks'] = Fisher_Jenks
        scheme = scheme.lower()
        if scheme not in schemes:
            raise ValueError("Invalid scheme. Scheme must be in the set: %r" % schemes.keys())

        binning = schemes[scheme](values, k)

        return binning

    except ImportError: 
        raise ImportError("PySAL is required to use the 'scheme' keyword")
```

I think the problem is from **pysal.esda.mapclassify** and I looked at the Pysal package I have installed, but under the Pysal founder I didn't find the `pysal\esda\mapclassify` path. Here is how the `..\Python\Lib\site-packages\pysal` on my computer looks like:

- __pycache__
- explore
- lib
- model
- viz
- __init__.py

I did find the mapclassify folder but it is under 'viz' instead of 'esda'.

Is it the version problem?

Update: Thank to the answer from [@martinfleis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9978945/martinfleis) **I downgraded the pysal into 1.14.4.** But now the new error raise:

```
........
........
  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 881, in _update_property
    raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)

AttributeError: Unknown property scheme
```

Answer (score 1):

PySAL 2.0 has a new structure. There is a fix for GeoPandas coming soon ([like today](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/911#issuecomment-469582810)). You can either wait for that (version 0.4.1) or use GeoPandas from master via `pip install git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git`. Or alternatively downgrade PySAL to 1.x.

Comment: Thanks for response. I followed the discussion on github and I downgraded PySAL to 1.14.4. But the new error raised as `  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 881, in _update_property
    raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)
AttributeError: Unknown property scheme`

Comment: I am not sure about this error, but GeoPandas just released bug fix for this incompatibility, so you should be able to use latest versions of both now.

Comment: I have this problem running your code: 
  Running command git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git /private/var/folders/b6/s2yt84g90sd36gkn9sjh0vxr0000gn/T/pip-req-build-_6ggqa2z
  fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
  github.com[0: 140.82.121.4]: errno=Operation timed out

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error:

I simply upgraded every related package (with the last available, according to each package's website):

````
pip install --upgrade  mapclassify==2.5.0
pip install --upgrade  geopandas==0.12.2
pip install --upgrade  pysal==2.6
```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install geopandas==0.4.0

pip install mapclassify

pip install pysal==2.0.0

pip install -U --no-deps mapclassify git+git://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git@master
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide context to your answer explaining the commands: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after upgrading GeoPandas to 0.10. So the problem seems to be persistent.

`pip install --upgrade  pysal==1.14.4`

Did the trick for me. Usage context:

```
gdf.plot(column='impedance', 
            cmap='YlOrRd', 
            label=gdf['impedance'], 
            scheme='quantiles',   **<===========**
            legend=True,
            k=10,
            ec='black',
            lw=.5,
            ax=ax)
```